# Change colours of different shapes using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to apply the following conditions to generate random colour for ALL 9 blocks shown in Figure 1.
[image: Figure 1]

a) Randomly apply 4 blocks of the SAME colour from the colour code information
table provided. The colour MUST be different from the rest of the 5 blocks.

b) Randomly apply 3 blocks of the SAME colour from the colour code information
table provided. The colour MUST be different from the rest of the 6 blocks.

c) Randomly apply 2 blocks of the SAME colour from the colour code information
table provided. The colour MUST be different from the rest of the 7 blocks.

Color Code Information Table:

```
#800000,
#A36386,
#FFD4D8,
#223CFF,
#F5FF5A,
#FF5555,
#A7EBFF
```

```js
var abcArray = ["#800000", "#A36386", "#FFD4D8", "#223CFF", "#F5FF5A", "#FF5555", "#A7EBFF"];

function run() {
  var abcArray = ["#800000", "#A36386", "#FFD4D8", "#223CFF", "#F5FF5A", "#FF5555", "#A7EBFF"];

  var table = document.getElementsByClassName("spanrows2")[0];
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  var td = document.createElement("td");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("Question 1 number: 1");

  table.appendChild(tr);
  td.appendChild(txt);
  tr.appendChild(td);
}

window.addEventListener("load", run, false);
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Arial", "sans-serif";
}

table {
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%
}

td {
  width: 700px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.spanrows1,
.spanrows2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.spanrows1 {
  width: 400px;
}

.spanrows2 {
  width: 600px;
}

.span2rows {
  text-align: left;
}

.squareDivs {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.squareTxt {
  line-height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.alignTxt {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="alignTxt"><span id="titleTxt"></span></div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class='spanrows2'>
      <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
      <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
      <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
      <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
      <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
      <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
      <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
      <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
      <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `document.getElementsByClassName`.

This method can get all elements with a particular class name. Here is the [documention](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName).

With that you will be able to get your elements.

In order to make things random, you will have to make the computer randomly generate some sort of true/false value. In order to accomplish this, `Math.Random` should work fine. Here is the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).

I am intentionally excluding code examples, as this is an assignment. I have mentioned some particularly useful functions and provided links to the documentation on these functions. My intention in doing this, is to have you read about the functions and try to implement them yourself.

If you are having trouble getting things to work with those 2 functions, don't be afraid to ask for more help here. :)